Colpitts oscillator not working observed in oscilloscope
I built a Colpitts oscillator with few parameters which I calculated for the oscillation and the amplifying for its proper working like expected. It is oscillating somehow, but the voltage for this circuit seems to be laggy. I tested it in Ltspice everything is fine, but when I boot it up it is not working and the frequency is not that, I calculated before. The expected range should be about 80 MHz - 120 MHz. The oscilloscope shows much lower frequencies, I do not need. Why could this happen? Below are pics for description:
By the way, in the file of LTspice, I did not use a decoupling capacitor across voltage. But the soldered circuit has an 100 nF capacitor for info.



LTspice .asc file
Version 4
SHEET 1 968 680
WIRE 224 16 0 16
WIRE 544 16 224 16
WIRE 0 48 0 16
WIRE 224 48 224 16
WIRE 512 128 224 128
WIRE 800 128 512 128
WIRE 224 160 224 128
WIRE 512 160 512 128
WIRE -80 208 -96 208
WIRE 0 208 0 128
WIRE 0 208 -32 208
WIRE 160 208 0 208
WIRE 800 208 800 128
WIRE 224 272 224 256
WIRE 304 272 224 272
WIRE 512 272 512 224
WIRE 512 272 304 272
WIRE 592 272 512 272
WIRE 0 288 0 208
WIRE 224 288 224 272
WIRE 304 288 304 272
WIRE 512 288 512 272
WIRE 592 288 592 272
WIRE 0 400 0 368
WIRE 160 400 0 400
WIRE 224 400 224 368
WIRE 224 400 160 400
WIRE 304 400 304 352
WIRE 304 400 224 400
WIRE 512 432 512 352
WIRE 576 432 512 432
WIRE 592 432 592 352
WIRE 592 432 576 432
WIRE 800 432 800 288
WIRE 800 432 592 432
WIRE 160 496 160 400
WIRE -96 560 -96 208
WIRE 576 560 576 432
WIRE 576 560 -96 560
FLAG 160 496 0
FLAG 544 96 0
SYMBOL res 208 32 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 560
SYMBOL res 208 272 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 220
SYMBOL res -16 32 R0
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 6.8k
SYMBOL res -16 272 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 3.3k
SYMBOL cap -32 192 R90
WINDOW 0 0 32 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 32 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 10n
SYMBOL npn 160 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q1
SYMATTR Value BF199
SYMBOL cap 288 288 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 100p
SYMBOL voltage 544 0 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 8
SYMBOL cap 496 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName C3
SYMATTR Value 68p
SYMBOL cap 496 288 R0
SYMATTR InstName C4
SYMATTR Value 10p
SYMBOL ind 784 192 R0
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 0.1µ
SYMBOL cap 576 288 R0
SYMATTR InstName C5
SYMATTR Value 4.7p
TEXT 464 376 Left 2 ;trimmer cap C5 -> 22p -> 4.7p
TEXT -102 520 Left 2 !.tran 0 10u 9u 250n



Alligator clips? Those aren't probes, they're antennas!  Have you tried with a proper 10x probe?

yes. 10x probe. The alligator clips are for battery supply.

C1 adds the base / emitter capacitance to the tank. This is parallel to C4 and C5.

Odd choice connecting C2/3/4/5 together but OK. The oscillator will not cover the full 40MHz range with the shown trimmer cap value. Theroretically the frequency should be variable around ~100MHz. As all components have (very) long leads that act as additional inductors it is hard to predict where oscillation will really occur. The scope shows ~55MHz which is quite far from the intended range. Check at least if all the components have the correct value.

Did you consider the influence of parasitic capacities and inductivities? Did you read the datasheet of the BF199 very carefully?
